# Text search in MongoDB, keyword search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-plugins

I'm trying to do a keyword search in my mongoDB database. In the mongoDB console:

```
db.logs.find({$text: {$search: 'key1'}})
```

gives the correct result. But when I use mongoose-text-search on my nodejs controller I get an error. This is the definition of the schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var textSearch = require('mongoose-text-search');

var Log = new Schema({
    keywords: [String],
    description: String,
    videoId: String,
    logId: String,
    date: Date,
    robot: String
});

Log.plugin(textSearch);
Log.index({ keywords: 'text' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('log', Log);
```

and in the controller, at certain point I do:

```
Log.textSearch('key1', function(err,output) {
    if (err){
        res.send(500,err);
    } else {
        console.log(output);
    }           
});
```

and the response is:

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"no such command: text","ok":0,"errmsg":"no such command: text","code":59,"bad cmd":{"text":"logs","search":"key1"}}
```

now, that message alone would make you think that text search is not working, but it is as I showed before. I'm running MongoDB shell version 3.0.2 so text search is enabled by default.

Comment: That plugin was created using the old "db command form" of text searching before it was integrated into normal queries for MongoDB in 2.6. I believe that command is deprecated in MongoDB 3.0.x series.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... so if I'm using mongoose, I should do a normal query? everywhere I find links and people recommending the usage of that plugin.

Comment: Using the normal query form would be advised, if not only for it seems to be the method that is up to date with the supported methods on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I was having a hard time following moongose's documentation... as it turns out, this is very easy to do in a normal query (no need for a plugin). Just to give an idea of how it can be done (not my actual code but one used to test the idea)

```
router.get('/keywordsearch', function (req,res) {

        var query = Log.find();

        var findKeywords = [];
        if (req.query.keywords != '')
        {
            var words = req.query.keywords.split(",");

            for (ii=0; ii<words.length; ii++)
                findKeywords[ii] = {keywords: words[ii].trim()};

            console.log(findKeywords);
            query.or(findKeywords);
        }

        query.exec(function (err,logs) {
            if (err){
                res.send(500,err);
            } else {
                req.logsList = logs;

                res.render('searchdb',{user:req.user,logs:req.logsList});
            }
        });

});
```

which means you can do a keyword search using:

```
find({keyword: 'blablabla'})
```

and using the OR logical operator for many keywords.